# Is this a secure way to authenticate a session?

Tags: php, content-management-system

Im building an admin panel for a website, I have my authentication code written, but Im not sure how secure it is.

This is not the login script, but it will utilize some session variables set by the login script.

Anyway, here it is, hope you will check it out for me (:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {    
//Prevent hijacking of the session
    $recreatesignature = $_SESSION['signature']; //signature (old)
    $recreatessalt = $_SESSION['salt']; //session salt (old)
    $useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; //useragent (new)
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //ip (new)

    $signature = $salt.sha1($ip.$recreatessalt.$useragent); //signature (hash)

    //Compare signatures
    if (!($recreatesignature==$signature)) {
        header(sprintf("Location: %s", $domain));   
        exit();
    }

//Session timeout
    if ((isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] >     $sessiontimeout)))  {
        //destroy session
        session_destroy();   
        session_unset();  
        //redirect to home page
        header(sprintf("Location: %s", $domain));
    }
    $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); 

//Generate new session id to make hijacking harder
    session_regenerate_id(TRUE);
}
```

Comment: All of this looks like stuff that your session framework should be doing itself... Honestly, I think here you should just trust that if `$_SESSION` is populated, it is valid. Do the security at a lower level.

Comment: looks cool. I had a similar idea once, but I used the top two parts of the IP number only so that the user stays logged in if his DSL gets disconnected. Not sure how this works with IPv6.

Comment: Looks good to me.. Providing it's done over https

Comment: Rule 1 for security code: Leave security code to the experts. If you have to ask "is it secure", then the answer is almost certainly "no". Use a PHP security patch like Suhosin; it does all of this and more beind the scenes. Problem solved without you having to risk doing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Looks perfect, but it will require https to prevent packet sniffing for full "safety"

As for Adder's idea with the first two subnet's of their IP, you could look at doing a basic geo2ip for further verification if data is highly sensative.

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty good. But User Agent and IP are easy to spoof, so that leaves everything to the salt in regards to the signature. I'd recommend a rather large salt then. And as others have pointed out, HTTPS must be used - and then you would also need to make sure the certificate used hasn't been compromised (as is evidently [far too easy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7Wl2FW2TcA)).